# How to input multiple files from a list of files in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of files in `bam_files.txt` which looks like this:

```
/home/test/2cells_2_trim.bam
/home/test/6h_1_trim.bam
/home/test/2cells_1_trim.bam
/home/test/6h_2_trim.bam
```

I want to do something like this:

```
cuffnorm -o cuffnorm_out /home/software/genes.gtf test/*.bam
```

but while reading files from `bam_files.txt` and not directly from directory (as shown above).

I want to read all the files together in the same command.

Can someone please help?
Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could read `bam_files.txt` into an array, then use the array as arguments to `cuffnorm`:

```
mapfile -t bam_files < bam_files.txt
cuffnorm -o cuffnorm_out /home/software/genes.gtf "${bam_files[@]}"
```

Comment: @Goku looks like steeldriver deleted his answer?

Comment: don't know why but here is his answer. this also works                     
`xargs -d '\n' cuffnorm -o cuffnorm_out /home/genes.gtf < bam_files.txt`     Thanks